# nvD3: Chart won't appear on dynamically-created DIV

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I made a button that adds `div`s to my DOM, as well as forms for adding data that I want made into charts for each `div`.

Here's `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.square {
            background-color: #ccc;
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addSomething()">add</button>
  <button ng-click="removeSomething()">remove</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="item.hed">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subhead" ng-model="item.subhed">
    <br>
    <form id="{{'customize-chart-' + item.number}}" novalidate>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste comma-separated data here." ng-model="textModel"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="{{'update-chart-' + item.number}}" ng-click="updateChart(item.number)">Update chart</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h3>{{item.hed}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.subhed}}</p>
    <div class="square">
        <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `app.js`:

```
var chNum=      1;
var maxCharts=  4;
var minCharts=  1;

var app=    angular.module("myApp",["nvd3"]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.items=   [
        {
            hed: '',
            subhed: '',
            number: chNum
        }
    ];

    $scope.textModel=   '';

    $scope.addSomething=    function(){
        if (chNum===maxCharts){
            return false;
        }
        chNum += 1; 
        $scope.items.push({
            hed:'',
            subhed:'',
            number: chNum   
        });
    };

    $scope.removeSomething= function(){
        if (chNum===minCharts){
            return false;
        }
        $scope.items.splice(-1,1);
        chNum -= 1;
    };

    $scope.updateChart= function(passedItemNumber){
        var data=   this.textModel
            .split(',')
            .map(function(d){
                return d;
            });
        console.log(data);

        $scope.options= {
            chart: {
                type: "linechart",
                height: 400,
                margin: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 20
                },
                x: function(d){
                    return d.x;
                },
                y: function(d){
                    return d.y;
                },
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: "X axis"
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: "Y axis"
                },

            }
        };

        $scope.data=    data;
    };
});
```

Here's the contents of `data.csv`, which I paste into the `textarea` input:

```
date,dow,sp500,nasdaq
1/1/16,10,15,8
1/3/16,5,3,7
1/5/16,12,18,12
```

I want to be able to paste data into the `textarea`, then click the "Update chart" `button`, and see the data appear in `div.square`, but nothing happens when I do that.

I also want to be able to do the same with other `div.square` elements I add to the DOM after I click the "add" `button` element.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: your data FORMAT is not correct.

Comment: @btinoco how must it be formatted?

Comment: not familiar much with nvd3 but check this plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/u3KjjRyM4Tp8K4CfEdAz?p=preview  it is your code with data coming from a function.